# Pass a string value from one route function to other in python

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a flask project.

I have created a from with following description

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class SearchRestaurantForm(FlaskForm):
    query = StringField('Query', validators=[DataRequired()])
    searchButton = SubmitField('Search')
```

This form is accessed in a route function named `search` as shown below.

```
@app.route("/search", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    form = SearchRestaurantForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        query_ = form.query.data
        return redirect('/result?query='+query_)
    return render_template('search.html', title='Search', form = form)
```

I want to use the data of the `StringField query` in another route function named `result` as shown below.

```
@app.route("/result", methods=['GET'])
def result():
    query__ = query_
    restaurants = find_appro_res(query__)
    return render_template('result.html', res_list=restaurants)
```

I don't know how can I access the `str` of `search` function in `result` function.

I am new in flask.

Comment: You should only use one single function here...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the request parameter to use in endpoints in flask, you can always use flask's [request](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.request) To access incoming request data, you can use the global `request` object of flask.

For solving your problem modify the `result` function as below:

```
from flask import request
@app.route("/result", methods=['GET'])
def result():
   query__ = request.args.get('query') # This will capture the request argument
   restaurants = find_appro_res(query__)
   return render_template('result.html', res_list=restaurants)
```